# OpenCV camera calibration fails on simulated data

Tags: python, opencv

If I

1. define an intrinsic camera matrix `A` and poses `[rvec, ...], [tvec, ...]`,
2. use them as parameters in `cv2.projectPoints` to generate the the images that would be generated by a camera when it views  a grid of circles,
3. Detect the features (`cv2.findCirclesGrid`) in the resulting images
4. Use `cv2.calibrateCamera` on the feature detections to recover the camera parameters

Shouldn't I recover the original intrinsic and extrinsic parameters?

The full code at the bottom of this question does this process, but does not
recover the original camera parameters:

```
Kept 4 full captures out of 4 images
calibration error  133.796093439
Simulation matrix: 
    [[  5.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   3.20000000e+02]
     [  0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+03   2.40000000e+02]
     [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
Estimated matrix: 
    [[   1.0331118     0.          317.58445168]
     [   0.          387.49075886  317.98450481]
     [   0.            0.            1.        ]]
```

I.e. the mean error is huge, and the estimated camera matrix does not look like
the simulation camera matrix orginally used to generate the test images.

I'd expect that this sort of closed-loop simulation should result in a very good estimate of the intrinsic camera matrix.  What am I doing wrong that this approach for validating `cameraCalibration` doesn't seem to work?

**Edits** in response to AldurDisciple comment

1) Added new function in code below `direct_generation_of_points` that skips
   the image generation functions and uses `cv2.projectPoints` directly to 
   compute the circle locations that are passed into `cv2.calibrateCamera`.
   *This works correctly.*

But this is confusing: the estimated circle locations (derived from my simulated 
images) are typically within about a 10'th of a pixel from the exact ones, the main
difference is that the points are in a different order:

```
# compare the y-component's
In [245]: S.dots[0][:,0,1]
Out[245]: 
array([ 146.33618164,  146.30953979,  146.36413574,  146.26707458,
        146.17976379,  146.30110168,  146.17236328,  146.35955811,
        146.33454895,  146.36776733,  146.2612915 ,  146.21359253,
        146.23895264,  146.27839661,  146.27764893,  177.51347351,
        177.57495117,  177.53858948,  177.48587036,  177.63012695,
        177.48597717,  177.51727295,  177.5202179 ,  177.52545166,
        177.57287598,  177.51008606,  177.51296997,  177.53715515,
        177.53053284,  177.58164978,  208.69573975,  208.7252655 ,
        208.69616699,  208.73510742,  208.63375854,  208.66760254,
        208.71517944,  208.74360657,  208.62438965,  208.59814453,
        208.67456055,  208.72662354,  208.70921326,  208.63339233,
        208.70820618,  239.8401947 ,  240.06373596,  239.87176514,
        240.04118347,  239.97781372,  239.97572327,  240.04475403,
        239.95411682,  239.80995178,  239.94726562,  240.01327515,
        239.82675171,  239.99989319,  239.90107727,  240.07745361,
        271.31692505,  271.28417969,  271.28216553,  271.33111572,
        271.33279419,  271.33584595,  271.30758667,  271.21173096,
        271.28588867,  271.3387146 ,  271.33770752,  271.2104187 ,
        271.38504028,  271.25054932,  271.29376221,  302.52420044,
        302.47903442,  302.41482544,  302.39868164,  302.47793579,
        302.49789429,  302.45016479,  302.48071289,  302.50463867,
        302.51422119,  302.46307373,  302.42077637,  302.60791016,
        302.48162842,  302.46142578,  333.70709229,  333.75698853,
        333.64157104,  333.64926147,  333.6647644 ,  333.69546509,
        333.73342896,  333.76846313,  333.57540894,  333.76605225,
        333.74307251,  333.60968018,  333.7739563 ,  333.70132446,
        333.62057495], dtype=float32)

In [246]: S.exact_dots[0][:,0,1]
Out[246]: 
array([ 146.25,  177.5 ,  208.75,  240.  ,  271.25,  302.5 ,  333.75,
        146.25,  177.5 ,  208.75,  240.  ,  271.25,  302.5 ,  333.75,
        << snipped 10 identical rows >>
        146.25,  177.5 ,  208.75,  240.  ,  271.25,  302.5 ,  333.75,
        146.25,  177.5 ,  208.75,  240.  ,  271.25,  302.5 ,  333.75,
        146.25,  177.5 ,  208.75,  240.  ,  271.25,  302.5 ,  333.75], dtype=float32)
```

Here's the working version of what I'm trying to do:

```
import scipy
import cv2
import itertools

def direct_generation_of_points():
    ''' Skip the part where we actually generate the image,
        just use cv2.projectPoints to generate the exact locations
        of the grid centers.

        ** This seems to work correctly **
    '''
    S=Setup()
    t=tvec(0.0,0.0,1.6) # keep the camera 1.6 meters away from target, looking at the origin
    rvecs=[ rvec(0.0,0.0,0.0), rvec(0.0, scipy.pi/6,0.0), rvec(scipy.pi/8,0.0,0.0), rvec(0.0,0.0,0.5) ]
    S.poses=[ (r,t) for r in rvecs ]
    S.images='No images: just directly generate the extracted circle locations'
    S.dots=S.make_locations_direct()
    calib_flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST|cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH
    calib_flags=calib_flags|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K4
    calib_flags=calib_flags|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K6
    S.calib_results=cv2.calibrateCamera( [S.grid,]*len(S.dots), S.dots, S.img_size, cameraMatrix=S.A, flags=calib_flags)
    print "calibration error ", S.calib_results[0]
    print "Simulation matrix: \n", S.A
    print "Estimated matrix: \n", S.calib_results[1]
    return S

def basic_test():
    ''' Uses a camera setup to 
        (1) generate an image of a grid of circles
        (2) detects those circles
        (3) generate an estimated camera model from the circle detections

        ** This does not work correctly **

    '''
    S=Setup()
    t=tvec(0.0,0.0,1.6) # keep the camera 1.6 meters away from target, looking at the origin
    rvecs=[ rvec(0.0,0.0,0.0), rvec(0.0, scipy.pi/6,0.0), rvec(scipy.pi/8,0.0,0.0), rvec(0.0,0.0,0.5) ]
    S.poses=[ (r,t) for r in rvecs ]
    S.images=S.make_images()
    S.dots=extract_dots( S.images, S.grid_size[::-1] )
    S.exact_dots=S.make_locations_direct()
    calib_flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST|cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH
    calib_flags=calib_flags|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K4|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5
    calib_flags=calib_flags|cv2.CALIB_FIX_K6
    S.calib_results=cv2.calibrateCamera( [S.grid,]*len(S.dots), S.dots, S.img_size, cameraMatrix=S.A, flags=calib_flags)
    print "calibration error ", S.calib_results[0]
    print "Simulation matrix: \n", S.A
    print "Estimated matrix: \n", S.calib_results[1]
    return S


class Setup(object):
    ''' Class to simulate a camera, produces images '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_size=(480,640)
        self.A=scipy.array( [ [5.0e3,   0.0, self.img_size[1]/2],
                              [  0.0, 5.0e3, self.img_size[0]/2],
                              [  0.0,   0.0,    1.0            ] ], 
                              dtype=scipy.float32 )
        # Nx, Ny, spacing, dot-size
        self.grid_spec=( 15, 7, 0.01, 0.001 )
        self.grid=square_grid_xy( self.grid_spec[0], self.grid_spec[1], self.grid_spec[2])     
        # a pose is a pair: rvec, tvec
        self.poses=[  ( rvec(0.0, scipy.pi/6, 0.0), tvec( 0.0,0.0,1.6) ),
                ]
    @property
    def grid_size(self):
        return self.grid_spec[:2]

    def make_images(self):
         return [make_dots_image(self.img_size, self.A, rvec, tvec, self.grid, self.grid_spec[-1] ) for (rvec,tvec) in self.poses]
    def make_locations_direct(self):
        return [cv2.projectPoints( self.grid, pose[0], pose[1], self.A, None)[0] for pose in self.poses]


def square_grid_xy( nx, ny, dx ):
    ''' Returns a square grid in the xy plane, useful
        for defining test grids for camera calibration
    '''
    xvals=scipy.arange(nx)*dx
    yvals=scipy.arange(ny)*dx
    xvals=xvals-scipy.mean(xvals)
    yvals=yvals-scipy.mean(yvals)
    res=scipy.zeros( [3, nx*ny], dtype=scipy.float32 )
    for (i,(x,y)) in enumerate( itertools.product(xvals, yvals)):
        res[:,i]=scipy.array( [x,y,0.0] )
    return res.transpose()


# single pixel dots were not detected?
#def make_single_pixel_dots( img_size, A, rvec, tvec, grid, dist_k=None):
#    rgb=scipy.ones( img_size+(3,), dtype=scipy.uint8 )*0xff
#    (dot_locs, jac)=cv2.projectPoints( grid, rvec, tvec, A, dist_k)
#    for p in dot_locs:
#        (c,r)=(int(p[0][0]+0.5), int(p[0][1]+0.5))
#        if 0<=c<img_size[1] and 0<=r<img_size[0]:
#            rgb[r,c,:]=0
#    return rgb

def make_dots_image( img_size, A, rvec, tvec, grid, dotsize, dist_k=None):
    ''' Make the image of the dots, uses cv2.projectPoints to construct the image'''
    # make white image
    max_intensity=0xffffffff
    intensity=scipy.ones( img_size, dtype=scipy.uint32)*max_intensity
    # Monte-Carlo approach to draw the dots
    for dot in grid:
        deltas=2*dotsize*( scipy.rand(1024, 3 )-0.5) # no. of samples must be small relative to bit-depth of intensity array
        deltas[:,2]=0
        indicator=scipy.where( scipy.sum( deltas*deltas, 1)<dotsize*dotsize, 1, 0.0)
        print "inside fraction: ", sum(indicator)/len(indicator)

        (pts,jac)=cv2.projectPoints( dot+deltas, rvec, tvec, A, dist_k )
        pts=( p for (ind,p) in zip(indicator, pts) if ind )
        for p in pts: 
            (c,r)=( int(p[0][0]+0.5), int( p[0][1]+0.5 ) )
            if r>=0 and c>=0 and c<img_size[1] and r<img_size[0]:
                intensity[r,c]=intensity[r,c]-6
            else:
                print "col, row ", (c,r), " point rejected"
    # rescale so that image goes from 0x0 to max intensity
    min_intensity=min(intensity.flat)
    # normalize the intensity
    intensity=0xff*( (intensity-min_intensity)/float(max_intensity-min_intensity)  )
    pixel_img=scipy.ones( intensity.shape+(3,), dtype=scipy.uint8 )
    return (pixel_img*intensity[:,:,scipy.newaxis]).astype(scipy.uint8 ) 

def extract_dots( img_list, grid_size ):
    '''
        @arg img_list: usually a list of images, can be a single image 
    '''
    # convert single array, into a 1-element list
    if type(img_list) is scipy.ndarray:
        img_list=[img_list,]

    def get_dots( img ):
        res=cv2.findCirclesGridDefault( img, grid_size)
        if not res[0]: # sometimes, reversing the grid size will make the detection successful
            return cv2.findCirclesGridDefault( img, grid_size[::-1] )
        return res

    all_dots=[ get_dots( img) for img in img_list]
    #all_dots=[cv2.findCirclesGrid( img, grid_size[::-1] ) for img in img_list ]
    full_captures=[x[1] for x in all_dots if x[0] ]
    print "Kept {0} full captures out of {1} images".format( len(full_captures), len(img_list) )
    if len(full_captures)<len(img_list):
        print "\t", [x[0] for x in all_dots]
    return [scipy.squeeze(x) for x in full_captures]

# convenience functions
def vec3_32(x,y,z):
    return scipy.array( [x,y,z], dtype=scipy.float32 )
rvec=vec3_32
tvec=vec3_32



if __name__=="__main__":
    basic_test()
```

Comment: `cv2.__version__` is `2.4.8`

Comment: I am quite sceptical about the way you are generating observed points using simulated views of the circle grid. Did you check visually the resulting images? Also, did you try to use `calibrateCamera` directly on the points obtained via `projectPoints`, i.e. without using those simulated images?

Comment: @AldurDisciple yes I verified the images.  Have now tried directly generating the center-locations -- that works.  However, the resulting centers are not significantly different than the ones detected in my simulated imagery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue is in the organization of the grid points passed in the first argument of `cv2.calibrateCamera`,
in the question  the points are organized in column major order, so to speak, and need to be organized in row-major order:

```
def square_grid_xy_fixed( nx, ny, dx ):
    ''' Returns a square grid in the xy plane, useful
        for defining test grids for camera calibration
    '''
    xvals=scipy.arange(nx)*dx
    yvals=scipy.arange(ny)*dx
    xvals=xvals-scipy.mean(xvals)
    yvals=yvals-scipy.mean(yvals)
    res=scipy.zeros( [3, nx*ny], dtype=scipy.float32 )
    # need to have "x" be the most rapidly varying index, i.e.
    # it must be the final argument to itertools.product
    for (i,(y,x)) in enumerate( itertools.product(yvals, xvals)):
        res[:,i]=scipy.array( [x,y,0.0] )
    return res.transpose()
```

Comment: How did you know that the points needed to be in row major order (grid-wise)? This isn't mentioned in the documentation.